# Share class between endpoint and Objectify with different field subset

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

Say this is my classes

```
@Entity
public class Library{
...
}

@Entity
public class Book{
    @Load
    @Parent
    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    private Ref<Library> libraryRef;

    @Ignore
    private Library library;
}
```

I want to send `List<Book>` to the "android" client: I don't want the android client to get `libraryRef` but I want the client to get `library`

Here is the data access method I have now

```
public static List< Book > getAllBooks(){
    return OfyService.ofy().load().type(Book.class).list();
}
```

My endpoint will just return `List<Book>` to android. I believe I have accomplished the first part: make sure datastore does not store `library` but `libraryRef`. But how do I accomplish the second part: make sure the client gets `library`?

I am sure it is not yet loaded. How do I make sure it is loaded? Do I have to use my own for-loop for iteration?

Comment: Using the `@ApiResourceProperty` should work already, even if you return `List<Book>` instead of `Book`. If it doesn't, it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice for anyone working with code shared between client and server is to make a clean separation between your API objects and your domain objects. It's a little more work up front to make DTOs but it makes your whole system more flexible - if you want to change your domain objects, you don't risk breaking a zillion mobile phone apps that are on a slow (or nonexistant) upgrade cycle.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I will think about it. My reluctance to implement what you are suggesting is that I have to iterate through the list of Book `List<Book>` I get from Objectify to create a `List<ClientSafeBook>`. Yes, it's `O(n)` but the coefficient may be as large as 20 to 50. Still thanks for the opinion.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the proportional cost of various computing operations. The cost of translating 20 or 50 entities is utterly dwarfed by the cost of loading those things out of the datastore and sending them across the wire to the app. Ignore O(n) operations and only optimize when you have known performance issues. Premature optimization and all that.